# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of null using popover

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm using onsen-ui 1.3.13 and I get this error that I don't understand:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of null using popover   @   loader.js:1450

I basically have 1 button, when I click it, I have 1 popover showing up with 2 other button. button 2 does a simple pop on an array. It worsk but give me this error right after.

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controler.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/readable-range.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sliding_menu.css">
</head>
<body>

    <ons-sliding-menu main-page="initial.html" menu-page="menu.html" max-slide-distance="260px" type="overlay" var="menu" side="left" close-on-tap>
    </ons-sliding-menu>

    <ons-template id="menu.html">
        <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
            <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent">
                <div class="right">
                    <ons-toolbar-button class="menu-closeMenu" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
                        </ons-icon>Close
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
            </ons-toolbar>

            <ons-list class="menu-list" ng-controller="PopoverController">
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('initial.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-gbp"></ons-icon>
                    Initial page
                </ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="reset();menu.closeMenu()">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-gbp"></ons-icon>
                    reset
                </ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="popover.html">
        <ons-popover direction="down" cancelable>
                <ons-list>
                    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="alert(true, 'Sorry not available in this version')">
                        <ons-icon icon="fa-cloud"></ons-icon>
                        Save property
                    </ons-list-item>
                    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="reset(); destroy($event)" >
                        <ons-icon icon="fa-home"></ons-icon>
                        <label>Reset</label>
                    </ons-list-item>
                </ons-list>
        </ons-popover>
    </ons-template>
</body>
</html>
```

controler.js:

```
var app = ons.bootstrap('propertyDeal', ['onsen','angularMoment']);

    app.factory('Property', function () {

        /**
        * Constructor, with class name
        */
        function Property(newProperty) {
            this.id = newProperty.id;
            this.purchasePrice = newProperty.pprice;
            this.legaFee = newProperty.legal;
          }

        return {
            createNew: function(newProperty) {
                return new Property(newProperty);
            }
        };
    });


    app.factory('portfolio', function(Property){
        var portfolio = {};
        portfolio.list = [];

        portfolio.add = function(newProperty){
            var prop = Property.createNew(newProperty);
            portfolio.list.push(prop);
        };
        portfolio.remove = function(){
            var removed = portfolio.list.pop();
        };

        return portfolio;
    });

    app.controller('PopoverController', function($scope, portfolio) {
        $scope.popurl = function(url, e) {
            $scope.param = url; 

            ons.createPopover( $scope.param,{parentScope: $scope}).then(function(popover) {
                $scope.popover = popover;
                $scope.show(e);
            });

            $scope.show = function(e) {
                $scope.popover.show(e);
            };
            $scope.destroy = function(e) {
                $scope.popover.destroy(e);
            };
        };

        $scope.alert = function(material, message) {
            ons.notification.alert({
                message: message,
                modifier: material ? 'material' : undefined
            });
        };

        $scope.reset = function() {
            if (portfolio.list.length >= 1){
                portfolio.remove();
            }
        };
    });

    app.controller('ListCtrl', function(portfolio) {
        this.portfolio = portfolio.list;
    });

    app.controller('PostCtrl', function(portfolio){

        this.addProperty = function(newProperty){
            if (angular.isDefined(newProperty)) {
                newProperty.id = portfolio.list.length;
                portfolio.add(newProperty);
            }
        };
    });
```

initial.html

```
<ons-navigator>
<ons-page>
    <div class="container">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
                <ons-icon class="icon" icon="ion-android-share"></ons-icon>&nbsp;this is a test
            </div>
            <div class="right" ng-controller="PopoverController">
                <ons-toolbar-button id="android-share" ng-click="popurl('popover_share.html', $event)">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-android-share" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
                <ons-toolbar-button id="android-more" ng-click="popurl('popover.html', $event)">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-android-more-vertical" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h2>Page 1</h2>

        <ul class="list">
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="newProperty.id" placeholder="id">
            <li class="list__item">
                <span class="currency">£<input type="number" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" ng-model="newProperty.pprice" placeholder="Purchase price" required></span>
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <span class="currency">£<input type="number" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" ng-model="newProperty.legal" placeholder="Legal fees"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div ng-controller="PostCtrl as post">
        <button class="button" ng-click="post.addProperty(newProperty);menu.setMainPage('initial2.html')">Next <ons-icon icon="ion-arrow-right-b"></ons-icon></button>
        <p>{{newProperty}}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl as list">
        <p ng-repeat="prop in list.portfolio track by $index">
            New Property: {{prop.id}} - {{prop.purchasePrice}}: {{prop.legaFee}} </p>
    </div>
</ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

After adding the reset() to the sliding menu as well, I can also say that it works perfectly fine with the sliding menu so I think it's definitely a problem with popover but I don't know what.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that code you are creating and destroying the popover over and over again. The problem is not in `reset()` function but in `destroy()`. You are trying to destroy the popover while showing it and there is a timing problem. Internally it tries to check its position when it's been already destroyed. Even there is no disappearing animation right now since you just destroy it instead of hiding it.

The solution is to create the popovers once and after that show and hide them whenever you need. Hope it helps!

**Update**:

The way you are using it right now actually has a memory leak. You create the popover every time you click on the toolbar button and destroy it in `reset()` function. The problem is that if you show the popover and then click outsite it, it will be hidden and not destroyed, so next time you open the popover it creates another one. You can check your DOM and see that every time there is 1 more popover added.

The correct way to use the popover is creating it only once and then showing and hiding it when you need. You need to destroy it only when you don't need it anymore. There is a way to do it automatically:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.myPopover.destroy);
```

That will destroy the popover in the current scope when you change to another scope.

Comment: Hi Fran,

thanks for your help. Well, You may be right about the fact that I destroy it every time, but this is how I understand you are supposed to do it, otherwise it consume memory more and more after each call.
Anyway, I thought it could be the problem, and the error is still exactly the same without the destroy so even if you are right and I shouldn't use it, this is not what causes the problem here I'm afraid.

Comment: If I remove the destroy call in your example I don't get error anymore. Actually, the reason you don't get errors when you do the reset in the menu is that you are not destroying the popover there. And it does not consume more and more memory. You just need to call `popover.show()` instead of creating it again. It is just 1 popover object in memory and you change its CSS to show or hide, there is no way that consumes more and more memory.

Comment: Thank you Fran, I will test that again then, I might have missed something when I did. Really appreciate your help !

Comment: So I have tried again and I definitely still have the error. it doesn't appear directly when you click on the popover, but if you click on next, then it does.

Comment: @nocrack I just updated my answer with more information, I hope it's helpful. When you say errors appears when you click on next, well, you are setting a new main page and you didn't provide that code. In any case I guess the error is different since there is nothing related to the popover in next.

Comment: Hi Fran,
Well its called initial2.htm because I copied initial and renamed it initial2 for the puropose if the example. but it doesn't matter. You can add a blank page or whatever else you want, the error appears. 
If you click on next right away, there is no error. if you click on the popover then on next, the error appear so I still think this is related to the popover otherwise there would be an error every time.